# Access to Lotus Notes Calendar via PHP?

Tags: php, vba, rest, calendar, lotus-notes

**I try to get my Lotus Notes calendar entries via PHP.**

I read about the [REST API](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=API%20Documentation), but when I tried to access my calendar there is an forbidden error and it seems that to access the content, there must be some settings on the Lotus Notes Server (I cannot make this as the servers are hold by external admins)

I know that I cann access the entries via vba, like the guy in [this thread](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28339272/loop-all-calendar-entries-in-lotus-notes-in-vba.html#answer39784950) made. For this I only need the mail database .nsf and the server (for me it works with just "")

I'm sure that there must be a possibility to also get the wished content in PHP...

Please help me, a workaround by calling a vba file doing the job wouldn't be very nice ;-)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This [old article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-php/) describes how to use the Lotus Notes COM API in PHP. It also gives a couple of other alternatives, which you might find useful if you're not running your PHP server on a Windows host.